# Javascript progress to specific percentage and then back to 0

Tags: javascript, algorithm, progress-bar

I want to be able to progress from 0 to a given percent then back to 0.  I am currently too stupid to figure out what I am sure is very easy.  Right now I am just using a 0 to 1 progress scale to get to 100%.  The animation needs to remain the way it is so I cannot change how the current value is animated only how I calculate the progress along the way.

So just to clarify.  I want to go from 0 to a given percent in the in the total progression then back to 0 in the time the animation is running.  So if I want to pass in 0.5 somewhere the block would move to 50% of the total progress and then back to 0 in the animation time.  In this case it would be to 500.

Here is a simple example below:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/sqbfdov0/)

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.box');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

let aF = null;
let timeline = new TimelineLite({ paused: true })
            .to(el , 1, { x: '200px' , ease: Linear.easeNone })
            .progress(0);

let current = 0;
const target = 500;

const animate = () => {
 const diff = target - current;
  const delta = (diff < 1) ? 0 : diff * 0.05;
  if(delta){
   current += delta;
    aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }else{
    current = target;
   window.cancelAnimationFrame(aF);
    aF = null;
  }
  
  const progress = current / target;
  timeline.progress(progress);
  display.innerHTML = progress;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 current = 0;
  aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
})
```

```css
.display{
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  width: 200px;
}

.display{
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  width: 200px;
}

.box{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="display">0</div>
<button>Start</button>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't attempt to solve easing problems, but does solve your back-and-forth problem:

```
let progress = (current / target) * 2;
if(progress > 1) { 
    progress = 2 - progress
}
```

This multiplies your progress amount by 2 (so it progresses from 0 to 2, instead of 0 to 1). Then, if the progress is greater than 1, it starts subtracting it from 2.

At a few different points, this gives:

```
Actual progress  |  Progress displayed on bar
0                   0                       
0.1                 0.2   
0.25                0.5
0.45                0.9
0.5                 1
0.55                0.9
0.75                0.5
0.9                 0.2
1                   0
```

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.box');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

let aF = null;
let timeline = new TimelineLite({ paused: true })
            .to(el , 1, { x: '200px' , ease: Linear.easeNone })
            .progress(0);

let current = 0;
const target = 500;

const animate = () => {
 const diff = target - current;
  const delta = (diff < 1) ? 0 : diff * 0.05;
  if(delta){
   current += delta;
    aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }else{
    current = target;
   window.cancelAnimationFrame(aF);
    aF = null;
  }
  
  let progress = (current / target) * 2;
  if(progress > 1) { 
      progress = 2 - progress
  }
  timeline.progress(progress);
  display.innerHTML = progress;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 current = 0;
  aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
})
```

```css
.display{
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  width: 200px;
}

.display{
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  width: 200px;
}

.box{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="display">0</div>
<button>Start</button>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question but this only works if you assume you are going for 50% peak.  But the peak will be dynamic.  So what if you want it to peak at 30% or 75%.  That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Just change the multiplier, check and divider values

Comment: I don't think you understand correctly.  In your example the box will move to 100% and then back to 0.  I am trying to solve for the movement to go to say 50% or 30% and then back to 0 during the animation time.  So if it I need it to move to 50% or 30% then the progress should never exceed 0.5 or 0.3 respectively and then move back down to 0.

Comment: You can do that by just changing the constants in my code.

Comment: `timeline.progress(progress * 0.3);`, boom the code works for 30%.

Comment: `timeline.progress(progress * 0.5);`, boom 50%. See?